# Change the position of parsley-errors-list in parsleyjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsley.js

I am using [parsleyjs.org](http://parsleyjs.org/) to validate my forms.

The plugin creates a `ui.parsley-errors-list`  when an input has a validation error.

The problem is that the `.parsley-errors-list` is being placed just after the form element's "input, textarea, radio etc.." breaking my layout as follows:

[image]

```
<fieldset>
    <p>Checkboxs with a max</p>
    <label class="checkbox parsley-error">
        <input name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" required="" data-parsley-maxcheck="2" data-parsley-multiple="checkbox2" data-parsley-id="5492"> <span></span>
        <p>Normal</p>
    </label>
    <ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-multiple-checkbox2">
        <li class="parsley-required">This value is required.</li>
    </ul>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" data-parsley-multiple="checkbox2" data-parsley-id="5492">   <span></span>
        <p>Normal</p>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" data-parsley-multiple="checkbox2" data-parsley-id="5492">   <span></span>
        <p>Normal</p>
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

Instead, the `.parsley-errors-list` need to be positioned to be the last child/element within the container `<fieldset>`.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can set the error container with (at least) two ways.

1. **Change the container with DOM attributes**

   In cases where you only have one input (or group of inputs, like you do) and you want to change the container of the errors on those inputs, you can use `data-parsley-errors-container="#element"` ([see the docs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-field)). Here is an example (**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/tocuv3yp/)**)

   ```
   <fieldset>
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
           <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" required data-parsley-maxcheck="2" data-parsley-multiple="checkbox2" value="option1" data-parsley-errors-container="#checkbox-errors" /> 1
       </label>
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
           <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" data-parsley-maxcheck="2" data-parsley-multiple="checkbox2" value="option2" /> 2
       </label>
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
           <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" data-parsley-maxcheck="2" data-parsley-multiple="checkbox2" value="option3" /> 3
       </label>

       <div id="checkbox-errors"></div>
   </fieldset>
   ```

   Note the attribute `data-parsley-errors-container="#checkbox-errors"` on the first checkbox and the element `<div id="checkbox-errors"></div>` at the end of the fieldset.

   In this case you don't need to add the `data-parsley-errors-container` to all checkboxes because you're "grouping" them with `data-parsley-multiple="checkbox2"`.
2. **Set a custom configuration to be used by Parsley**

   In cases where you have a few or all inputs and you want to change the position of the default container. Lets say all your fields are placed inside a fieldset and you want to display the errors at the end of the fieldset.

   This solution allows you to change the default container for each field ([**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/qdk73z1r/2/))

   ```
   <fieldset>
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
           <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" required data-parsley-maxcheck="2" data-parsley-multiple="checkbox2" value="option1" /> 1
       </label>
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
           <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" data-parsley-maxcheck="2" data-parsley-multiple="checkbox2" value="option2" /> 2
       </label>
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
           <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" data-parsley-maxcheck="2" data-parsley-multiple="checkbox2" value="option3" /> 3
       </label>

       <div id="checkbox-errors"></div>
   </fieldset>

   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var parsleyConfig = {
           errorsContainer: function(parsleyField) {
               var fieldSet = parsleyField.$element.closest('fieldset');

               if (fieldSet.length > 0) {
                   return fieldSet.find('#checkbox-errors');
               }

               return parsleyField;
           }
       };


       $("form").parsley(parsleyConfig);
   });
   </script>
   ```

   In this solution we've added the element `<div id="checkbox-errors"></div>` before the end of the fieldset and changed the `errorsContainer` option of Parsley. If our element is inside a fieldset the errors will be displayed inside the `#checkbox-errors`.

   Based on this example, you are also able to set the same container for all fields. In this case your options would be something like this ([**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/ncsek6b2/1/)):

   ```
   var parsleyConfig = {
       errorsContainer: function(parsleyField) {
           return $('#errors');
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: Can't I just change where it is being positioned? I just can't find the function that decides where the error container is positioned, can you help me find? because I might be able to achieve what i want by tweaking the code a bit with .closest("fieldset")

Comment: @Leo take a look at the updated answer. I think you're after the second approach. Let me know if it works.

Comment: The second option is exactly what I am looking for! Each fieldset will have its own errors so they won't be complained in one no. Can I achieve this by hacking the plugin rather adding an additional function? If not no worry will just use this function.

Comment: @Leo You can change the plugin to do that "automatically" but _I strongly advise against it_ because you'll lose the ability to easily use newer versions. If you really want to do that you should change the [code (ver.2.0.7)](http://parsleyjs.org/dist/parsley.js) around the line 1277.

Comment: I bared that into account. At the very top of the code document I commented out what I have changed. So when I update it to a new version I can just apply the changes again. Will have a look at the line, what would you recommend me to do? As I have tweaked the plugin to add the classes parsley-error and success to the filedsets as well using .closest(fieldset) - it worked, but they don't very applied to the filedsets containing a chosen select inputs until you click on them and again :/ - I had a look at the code and it actually adds class="" only

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of UI errors in the parsley js.
You can use the **data-parsley-errors-container** custom validator for placing the parsley error message as per your form needs.

```html
<div>
    <div class="radio radio-primary">
        <input type="radio" id="cellPhone1" value="1" name="rd_cell_phone" required="" data-parsley-error-message="Please select an option" data-parsley-errors-container="#cell-phone-validation-error-block">
        <label for="cellPhone1"> Yes </label>
    </div> 
    <div class="radio radio-primary">
        <input type="radio" id="cellPhone0" value="0" name="rd_cell_phone" required="" data-parsley-error-message="Please select an option" data-parsley-errors-container="#cell-phone-validation-error-block">
        <label for="cellPhone0"> No </label>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="margin-top10" id="cell-phone-validation-error-block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.listen('parsley:field:error', function(fieldInstance){
            var fieldName = fieldInstance.$element.attr('name');
            var field = $('input[name="'+fieldName+'"]');
            var fieldWrapper = field.parents('fieldset');
            if (fieldWrapper.find('.errors_container').length > 0) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    fieldWrapper.find('.errors_container').append(fieldWrapper.find('.parsley-errors-list'));
                },100);
            }
        });
        $('form').parsley();
}
```

Use class, because it works for many fields.