# Parsley error placement

Tags: error-handling, parsley.js

I'm using parsley validation now(super new with this validation) since the caldera form updated their plugin. Any ideas how to place the error messages above the field?

My previous implementation of the error messages is above the field and using jquery validation - error placement.

Thank you.

Comment: Follow steps mentioned in this stack question : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122028/change-the-position-of-parsley-errors-list-in-parsleyjs/55607844#55607844](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122028/change-the-position-of-parsley-errors-list-in-parsleyjs/55607844#55607844)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to obtain what you want with the right `errorContainer` option:

> Specify the existing DOM container where ParsleyUI should put the errors. It is also possible to configure it with a callback function from javascript, see the annotated source.